# Can't import load test results into Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing, sql-server-express, azure-devops

I haven't been able to store local load test results, nor import load test results from Visual Studio Online into Visual Studio 2015. I was able to do this previously, on a different machine, with Visual Studio 2013.

The error I get can be seen here: [image: error screen-shot]

And the error in the event log is:

> (devenv.exe, PID 5824, Thread 59) WebLoadTestAdapter: Exception
>   invoking SQL script loadtestresultsrepository.sql on SQL Server
>   instance Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated
>   Security=True: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows
>   Application event log for error details.

I've followed instructions here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182600(v=vs.140).aspx) on how to setup the load test respository, but it didn't help...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>SQLCMD /S localhost\sqlexpress /i loadtestresultsrepository.sql
Changed database context to 'LoadTest2010'.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure LoadTestTransactionResults2, Line 2
There is already an object named 'LoadTestTransactionResults2' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure LoadTestPageResultsByNetwork2, Line 2
There is already an object named 'LoadTestPageResultsByNetwork2' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure Prc_QueryLoadTestPageComparison, Line 2
There is already an object named 'Prc_QueryLoadTestPageComparison' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure Prc_QueryLoadTestTestComparison, Line 2
There is already an object named 'Prc_QueryLoadTestTestComparison' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure Prc_QueryLoadTestTransactionComparison, Line 2
There is already an object named 'Prc_QueryLoadTestTransactionComparison' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure Prc_QueryComputedCounterComparison, Line 2
There is already an object named 'Prc_QueryComputedCounterComparison' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure prc_QueryForMachinesInRun, Line 2
There is already an object named 'prc_QueryForMachinesInRun' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure Prc_QueryLoadTestErrorComparison, Line 2
There is already an object named 'Prc_QueryLoadTestErrorComparison' in the database.

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: I had a similar message recently. After clicking on the "Delete Temporary Files" button (as shown in @Vicky's answer) it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1). Be sure that the MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS service is running, and you're able to check the LoadTest2010 database in Server Explorer in VS.

2). Be sure that **Local test result store** is targeted to LoadTest2010 database in MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS service: Right-click the load test in Load Test Editor, and select **Manage Test Controllers**. Be sure that  you select the correct sql service and Test Connection is **success**.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the "Server Name" in Connection Properties was set to localdb\v11.0. Changing it to .\SQLEXPRESS solved the problem.